# Ruby on Rails: How to change the Foriegn Key values on a collection_select drop down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a drop down on my form which is a foreign key to another table:

```
<div class="field">
    <td><%= f.label "#{column_name}" %></td>
    <td><%= f.collection_select "#{column_name}", Table.all, :id, :message_id %></td>
</div>
```

"Table" has a column "message_id" which is a foreign_key to a different table "Messages".

The "Messages" table contains all the text/strings in my application.

When I load this code on my page it will give me a drop down list of all records but it will only show foreign key ID numbers pointing to the "Messages" table.

How can I change the foreign key ID numbers in the drop down to switch with message content I have on my Messages table?

Comment: Do you want the dropdown to display the message that the table has?

Comment: I need a drop down that contains the message content from the "Messages" table.

Like for example the output would be substituted with:

<%= Messages.find(x.message_id).message_content %>

Comment: can you show Message and Table models?

Comment: my model design is dependent on the database so I can't specify the tables.

But what I need is instead of showing fk ID's pointing to the Message record., it will show the :message_contents of that record.

Comment: What I meant by dependent, here's the contents of my model:

columns.each do |column|
  attr_accessible column.name.to_sym
  if column.type == :integer && !column.primary
    if column.null #true means nullable
    validates_numericality_of column.name.to_sym ,:allow_nil => true, :allow_blank => true
   else #false means NOT NULL
    validates_numericality_of column.name.to_sym
   end 
  end
  if !column.null && !column.primary
   validates_presence_of column.name.to_sym
  end 
 end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`f.input "#{column_name}", :collection => Table.all.collect {|t| [Messages.find(t.message_id).message_content , t.id]}`

It's not very efficient, but I think will do the work.

Comment: I'm getting an error

"undefined method `input' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x869ee69>"

Comment: Okay I ffound the issue, this method works but here's the changes I made:

f.select "#{column_name}", Table.all.collect {|t| [Messages.find(t.message_id).message_content , t.id]}

And you are right this indeed is inefficient, looking at the terminal there where so many trips to the db but it works.

Thank you for this

Comment: Maybe you should consider to review your relationships modeling and check if a polymorphic association will be more suitable for you

Comment: I'm new to rails so this is the first time I've heard of polymorphic association. I just found it on the rails documentation. Thank you for this mvidaurre.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method in your Table model that gets all the Message contents from the related Messages. Like:

```
#table.rb

    def message_content
        self.message.message_content #a trip to the database every select iteration over Table.all
    end
```

Of course that is not very good performance wise (look at all these trips to the DB). So you can use a before_save hook to associate the message content to your Table record:

```
    #table.rb
    before_save :associate_message_content

    def associate_message_content
      unless message.nil?
        self.message_content = message.message_content
      end       
    end     

    def message_content
        self.message_content #no trips to the database
    end
```

And in your select just call the method:

```
#view
<div class="field">
    <td><%= f.label "#{column_name}" %></td>
    <td><%= f.collection_select "#{column_name}", Table.all, :id, :message_content %></td>
</div>
```